# What are some useful data augmentation techniques for deep convolutional neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

**Background:**
I recently understood on a deeper level the importance of data augmentation when training convolutional neural networks after [seeing this excellent talk by Geoffrey Hinton](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929075327/http://d1baxxa0joomi3.cloudfront.net/69bf620e48d60761118dc4328f5d6e9c/basic.mp4).

He explains that current generation convolutional neural networks are not able to generalize the frame of reference of the object under test, making it hard for a network to truly understand that mirrored images of an object are the same.

Some research has gone into trying to remedy this. [Here is one of the many many examples](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5854-spatial-transformer-networks.pdf).
I think this helps to establish how critical data augmentation is today when training convolutional neural networks.

Data augmentation techniques are rarely benchmarked against each other. Hence:

**Questions:**

- What are some papers where the practitioners reported exceptionally better performance?
- What are some data augmentation techniques that you have found useful?

Answer (score 1):

> Sec. 1: Data Augmentation Since deep networks need to be trained on a
>   huge number of training images to achieve satisfactory performance, if
>   the original image data set contains limited training images, it is
>   better to do data augmentation to boost the performance. Also, data
>   augmentation becomes the thing must to do when training a deep
>   network.
>
> - There are many ways to do data augmentation, such as the popular    horizontally flipping, random crops and color jittering. Moreover,
>     you could try combinations of multiple different processing, e.g.,
>     doing the rotation and random scaling at the same time. In addition,
>     you can try to raise saturation and value (S and V components of the
>     HSV color space) of all pixels to a power between 0.25 and 4 (same
>     for all pixels within a patch), multiply these values by a factor
>     between 0.7 and 1.4, and add to them a value between -0.1 and 0.1.
>     Also, you could add a value between [-0.1, 0.1] to the hue (H
>     component of HSV) of all pixels in the image/patch.
> - Krizhevsky et al. [1](http://lamda.nju.edu.cn/weixs/project/CNNTricks/CNNTricks.html) proposed fancy PCA when training the famous    Alex-Net in 2012. Fancy PCA alters the intensities of the RGB
>     channels in training images. In practice, you can firstly perform PCA 
>     on the set of RGB pixel values throughout your training images. And
>     then, for each training image, just add the following quantity to
>     each RGB image pixel (i.e., I_{xy}=[I_{xy}^R,I_{xy}^G,I_{xy}^B]^T):
>     [bf{p}_1,bf{p}_2,bf{p}_3][alpha_1 lambda_1,alpha_2 lambda_2,alpha_3
>     lambda_3]^T where, bf{p}_i and lambda_i are the i-th eigenvector and
>     eigenvalue of the 3times 3 covariance matrix of RGB pixel values,
>     respectively, and alpha_i is a random variable drawn from a Gaussian
>     with mean zero and standard deviation 0.1. Please note that, each
>     alpha_i is drawn only once for all the pixels of a particular
>     training image until that image is used for training again. That is
>     to say, when the model meets the same training image again, it will
>     randomly produce another alpha_i for data augmentation. In [1](http://lamda.nju.edu.cn/weixs/project/CNNTricks/CNNTricks.html), they
>     claimed that “fancy PCA could approximately capture an important
>     property of natural images, namely, that object identity is invariant 
>     to changes in the intensity and color of the illumination”. To the
>     classification performance, this scheme reduced the top-1 error rate
>     by over 1% in the competition of ImageNet 2012.

[(Source: Must Know Tips/Tricks in Deep Neural Networks (by Xiu-Shen Wei))](http://lamda.nju.edu.cn/weixs/project/CNNTricks/CNNTricks.html)